# How to use a variable in a command inside of a bash file

Tags: bash, grep, quoting

I use this command directly on our redhat linux server 8.8 and it's working correctly and I get the result I want:

```
grep '01-FEB-2024' /u01/app/server1/listener_scan/trace/listener_scan.log | awk '{ if ( $NF != 0 ) print $0 }'
```

I need to automotize this procedure with a bash file and it looks like that it doesn't get the value of current_date variable:

```
#!/bin/bash
current_date=$(date "+%d-%b-%Y")
grep '$current_date' /u01/app/server1/listener_scan/trace/listener_scan.log | awk '{ if ( $NF != 0 ) print $0 }' >> y.out
grep "$current_date" /u01/app/server1/listener_scan/trace/listener_scan.log | awk '{ if ( $NF != 0 ) print $0 }' >> y.out
grep $current_date /u01/app/server1/listener_scan/trace/listener_scan.log | awk '{ if ( $NF != 0 ) print $0 }' >> y.out
```

In all of these cases it return an empty value.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `date "+%d-%b-%Y"` will return `06-Feb-2024`, not `06-FEB-2024`, so consider using `grep -i` for case insensitivity

Comment: It worked perfectly with -i. Thank you very much. If you post it I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do:

```
#!/bin/bash

current_date=$(date "+%d-%b-%Y")
grep -i "$current_date" /u01/app/server1/listener_scan/trace/listener_scan.log |
    awk '{ if ( $NF != 0 ) print $0 }' >> y.out
```

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> https://web.archive.org/web/20230224010517/https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words
> [when-is-double-quoting-necessary](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)

Answer (score 4):

`date +%d-%b-%Y` outputs the current date with the day of the month 0-padded to a length of 2, the user's locale month abbreviation, and the year 0-padded to 4 digits.

Depending on who runs that command, you may get something like:

```
06-فبر-2024
06-лют-2024
06-fév-2024
```

In the C/POSIX locale, you get:

```
$ LC_ALL=C date +%d-%b-%Y
06-Feb-2024
```

It looks like your log contains the same but in uppercase.

Here, you could do:

```
#! /bin/sh -
TODAY=$(LC_ALL=C date +%d-%b-%Y) exec awk '
  BEGIN{today = toupper(ENVIRON["TODAY"])}
  index($0, today) && $NF != 0
  ' /u01/app/server1/listener_scan/trace/listener_scan.log
```

`mawk`, busybox `awk` and `gawk` can get you that information by themselves, so on a Linux-based systems this is also very likely to work:

```
#! /bin/sh -
LC_ALL=C exec awk '
  BEGIN {today = toupper(strftime("%d-%b-%F"))}
  index($0, today) && $NF != 0
  ' /u01/app/server1/listener_scan/trace/listener_scan.log
```

(that also affects the way the contents of the log file is decoded into text, but that's likely for the best; that also affects the language of error messages if any)

Comment: Why `TODAY` UPPER CASE? Looks like they are used by system variables, maybe better to not using those?

Comment: @GillesQuénot because that's passed as an environment variable to `awk` (thanks for the edit btw)

Comment: Then, `awk -v today=xxx` looks more the way to go.

Comment: @GillesQuénot, I try to avoid `-v` in general as it mangles backslashes (not a problem here).

Answer (score 0):

You need to match on a pattern such as `06-FEB-2024`, but as was noted in a comment, the `date` command returns `06-Feb-2024`.

You can upper-case the variable:

```
current_date=$(LC_ALL=C date "+%d-%b-%Y")
grep "${current_date^^}" /u01/app/server1/listener_scan/trace/listener_scan.log |
    awk '{ if ( $NF != 0 ) print $0 }' >> y.out
```

Also you can merge the combination:

```
awk -v date="$(LC_ALL=C date +'%d-%b-%Y')" '$0 ~ toupper(date) && $NF!=0' /u01/app/server1/listener_scan/trace/listener_scan.log >>y.out
```

Comment: GNU `date` has an "upper case if possible" format flag `^` so you could use `%^b` in that case I think

Comment: $NF+0 is not the same as `$NF != 0`. It would fail to return lines that end in `foo` for instance. as by applying an arithmetic operation, you're converting `$NF` to a number